# Mails not going through with "Host not found" error

Tags: postfix, mailx

Mails are not going through from my `postfix` mail server  and it is failing with below error

```
   Jun 21 07:53:23 node-002 postfix/error[23121]: 06899101C478: to=<blas@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.02/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=node-001 type=A: Host not found)
```

My `postfix` configuration is as follows:

```
  relayhost = node-001
  inet_protocols = ipv4
  inet_interfaces = 172.17.0.1
  mynetworks = 10.25.110.205, 127.0.0.0/8, 10.25.100.66, 10.25.110.0/24, 10.25.100.67, 10.25.100.70, 10.200.64.0/20, 10.200.32.0/20, 172.17.0.0/24
```

If I check name resolution on `relayhost` , it is working fine

Please suggest to resolve this issue .

Comment: When you run `dig node-001` while logged into node-002, does it return any info?

Comment: Yeah... Name resolution works fine for node-001 from node-002